# Color of the cars

Tags: algorithm

Could you give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

How can I find out whether most cars have the same color if the only function I can use is to check whether two cars have the same color?

Comment: What is your definition of 'most'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With equality, you can first [build equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) classes and then count the largest one.

Comment: And there I was just about to write the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "list" where the color of the car is the key value and it counts how many cars of that color you have and stores a car of that color.

It goes something like this:

you will have a struct of with this fields:

```
struct color
  car *car_with_color = NULL
  int count = 0
```

so you go to the first car store it's color and add 1:

```
color[1].car_with_color=&cars[1];
color[1].count=1;
```

then for the next car you do:

```
if (cars[2].color == color[1].car_with_color->color)
  color[1].count++;
else
  color[2].car_with_color=&cars[2];
  color[2].count=1;
```

and so on:

```
for (i=1;i<=NUM_OF_CARS;i++){
  j=1;
  while (color[j].car_with_color != NULL){
    if (cars[i].color == color[j].car_with_color->color){
      color[i].count++;
      break;
    }else 
      j++;
  }
  if (color[j].car_with_color == NULL){
    color[j].car_with_color=&cars[i];
    color[j].count=1;
   }
 }
```

it's written in a `C` like pseudo-code.